# android:popupMenuStyle doesn't work with Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

In my action bar style I have a popup with drawble when I change Theme Theme.AppCompat.Light to Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar no work popupMenu.Mystyle

```
<style name="Theme.Mystyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Mystyle</item>
</style>
<style name="PopupMenu.Mystyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel</item>
</style>
```

I don´t undestand. should work with the two themes.
What happens?

Answer (score 2):

AppCompat defines and uses many attributes without the `android:` prefix.

```
<style name="Theme.Mystyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Mystyle</item>
</style>
```

This should fix your popup background.